# What do you call the container where you extract cow milk into?

Tags: word-request

I am not sure why, but I forgot the word. I know there's a general word for it, more specific than container, but I would also like to know is there's an even more specific word for it too.

For example:

> The farmer put a ___ under the cow and started extracting milk by
>   milking the cow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If milking by hand, each cow would normally have a **pail** or **bucket** put underneath her.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dairy_farming#Hand_milking) (emphasis mine):

> The first milking machines were an extension of the traditional *milking* ***pail***. The early milker device fit on top of a regular *milk* ***pail*** and sat on the floor under the cow. Following each cow being milked, the ***bucket*** would be dumped into a holding tank. These were introduced in the early 20th century.

Note that the author of the definition used there couldn't even make up their own mind between *pail* and *bucket*. (Or perhaps different authors were responsible for different parts of that entry.)